# What is .pivot_root files?

Tags: linux, docker, debian, root, cp

When copying files from the local machine to the docker container, using the `docker cp` in the file system of the container, the files .pivot_root appear. What are these files, what are they for?

Answer (score 0):

pivot_root() moves the root file system of the calling process to the directory put_old and makes new_root the new root file system of the calling process....

The typical use of pivot_root() is during system startup, when the system mounts a temporary root file system (e.g., an initrd), then mounts the real root file system, and eventually turns the latter into the current root of all relevant processes or threads...